# Java - get pixel color

Tags: java, get, compare, pixel

I am Java beginner and I am trying to code something. Currently I am stucked at getPixelColor(). It's the method of class Robot. I can get pixel color but don't know how to compare with other color. Let's say that my other color is stored in some int variable and I need to compare these two colors. But I can't compare these two colors, because it throws this error "incomparable types:int and java.awt.Color". So how convert it to int?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
if(color.getRGB() == stored_color){
}
```

Anyways, you need to access the Color object's getRGB function to compare the numeric value to another int.

Comment: while both answers (posted right now) will work, this one is better for memory and speed. +1.

Comment: so something like this?    int stored_color = 16777215;
    if(stored_color == robot.getPixelColor(300,300).getRGB()){} it doesn't throw any error, but it doesn't match color which it should match.

Comment: ok, I 've got it and it works :) I didn't know that it return color in dec_color=256^3-dec_color

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer! Glad to hear it worked out for you and apologies I couldn't get back to you sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Color otherColor = new Color(someInt);
```

and then

```
if (otherColor.equals(robot.getPixelColor(someX, someY))
{
     ...
}
```